JS Pointer. Can't receive another target at pointerup after moving finger
I'm trying to figure out pointer events. I need to receive two different targets, first - at pointerdown, then slide finger and get second target - at pointerup. Everything works fine with mouse, but on touch devices target at pointerup and pointerdown the same
I want to have abilities swap colors of dots on laptop and phone
I tried to check every event at pointerup, pointermove, pointercancel, pointerdown. With mouse I can change target, but it always the same target at touch device. No matter where I move my finger
JS
let grayArea = document.querySelector(".box");
let divArray = [];
let currentTile;
let otherTile;
let colors = [
    ['red', 'pink'],
    ['blue', 'orange']
];


window.onload = function () {
    createDiv();
}

function createDiv() {
    for (let r = 0; r < 2; r++){
        let row = []
        for (let c = 0; c < 2; c++){
            let dotElement = document.createElement ('div');
            dotElement.id = r + '-' + c;
            dotElement.className = 'dotElement';
            dotElement.innerText =  r + '-' + c;
            dotElement.draggable = true;
            dotElement.style.backgroundColor = colors[r][c];
            grayArea.appendChild(dotElement);
            row.push(dotElement);
        }
        divArray.push(row);
    }
}

grayArea.addEventListener ('pointerdown', e => {
    console.log(e);
    currentTile = e.target.id;
    console.log(currentTile);
    ondragstart = () => false; //prevent default dragAndDrop (only for mouse)
})

grayArea.addEventListener ('pointermove', e => {
    console.log('move');
})

grayArea.addEventListener ('pointercancel', e => {
    console.log(e);
})

grayArea.addEventListener ('pointerup', e => {
    console.log(e);
    otherTile = e.target.id;
    console.log(otherTile);
})

